# OpenVZ acl support for Samba

Tags: acl, openvz, xattr, samba4, proxmox

Setting up Samba-4.3.5 as AD domain fileserver in OpenVZ container, running in ProxMox (pve-manager/3.4-6/102d4547 running kernel: 2.6.32-39-pve). Hardware node has enabled acl support for */var/lib/vz*. Nevertheless, container has no acl support. So, any setfacl command does nothing.

How enable acl and xattr support in container?

Comment: Please post an answer. Editing the question is for adding additional information, to clarify it, or to repair it, not for answering it.

Comment: Putting SOLVED in the title in not the right way to finish a question, please click the check next to the response that answers your question. If you don't it will end up in the "unsolved" queue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added to /etc/pve/openvz/VMID.conf

```
MOUNT_OPTS="rw,realtime,acl,user_xattr"
```

Did the thing. Now (for example)

```
setfacl -m u:sshd:rwx ~/tmp
setfacl -m g:ssh:rwx ~/tmp
```

and then

```
getfacl ~/tmp
```

shows

```
 # file: root/tmp
 # owner: root
 # group: root
user::rwx
user:sshd:rwx
group::r-x
group:ssh:rwx
mask::rwx
other::r-x
```

So, ACL is OK